# How would you end this circuit

Tags: circuitikz

I want to draw a circuit like this one using circuitikz:
[image]

The red wires are the ones I don't know how to draw.

This is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}\draw
(0,4) node[and port] (A1) {A1}
(0,0) node[and port] (A2) {A2}
(6,4) node[and port] (A3) {A3}
(6,0) node[and port] (A4) {A4}
(4,2) node[and port] (A5) {A5}
(1,2) node[not port] (N) {}
(10,3) node[or port] (O1) {O1}
(10,1) node[or port] (O2) {O2}
(A1.out) -| (A3.in 1)
(A2.out) -| (A4.in 2)
(A3.out) -| (O1.in 1)
(A4.out) -| (O2.in 2)
(A5.out) -| (A3.in 2)
(A5.out) -| (A4.in 1)
(N.out)  -| (A5.in 1)
;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

The name of the gates are on the photo only to provide some identification on what is what. But are unnecessary when drawing the circuit, also that hop the wire at Q does over the red one is to specify that is not connected to it, but again in the drawing does not to be like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is important to learn to use relative coordinates and the anchors also to position elements, to avoid strange wires and to be able to change the circuit and re-use it with minimum effort. For example (but there are even more modular ways to do it, just no time now) this is one possibility; see the comments in the code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7]
\draw
% we position in an absolute way just these three ports
(0,5) node[and port] (A1) {A1}
(0,0) node[and port] (A2) {A2}
(4,2.5) node[and port] (A5) {A5}
% now is all relative
(A1.out) ++(5,0) node[and port, anchor=in 1] (A3) {A3}
(A2.out) ++(5,0) node[and port, anchor=in 2] (A4) {A4}
(A5.in 1) ++(-1,0) node[not port, circuitikz/logic ports/scale=0.6] (N) {}
(A3.out) ++(1,0) node[nor port, anchor=in 1] (O1) {O1}
(A4.out) ++(1,0) node[nor port, anchor=in 2] (O2) {O2}
(A1.out) -| (A3.in 1)
(A2.out) -| (A4.in 2)
(A3.out) -| (O1.in 1)
(A4.out) -| (O2.in 2)
(A5.out) -| (A3.in 2)
(A5.out) -| (A4.in 1)
(N.out)  -| (A5.in 1)
;
\draw [color=red]
% input leads
(A1.in 2) --++(-0.5,0) node[left]{J}
(A2.in 1) --++(-0.5,0) node[left]{K}
% N
(N.in) -- ++(-0.5, 0) coordinate(n1)
(A5.in 2) -| (n1)
(N.north) node[above]{N}
(n1) -- ++(-0.5,0) node[left]{CLK}
% output wires
(O1.out) --++(1,0) coordinate (o1) --++(1,0) coordinate(q1)
(O2.out) --++(1,0) coordinate (o2) --++(0.5,0) coordinate(q2) --++(0.5,0) coordinate(q3)
% crossing nors
(O1.in 2) -- ++(0,-1) coordinate(ao1) -- ++(1,0)  -- (o2)
(O2.in 1) -- ++(0,1) coordinate(ao2) -- ++(1,0)  -- (o1)
% long crossing
(q1) --++(0,-6) -| (A2.in 2)
(q2) --++(0,6) -| (A1.in 1)
% output leads 
(q1) to[short, -o] ++(0.5,0) node[right]{Q}
(q3) to [short, -o] ++(0.5,0) node[right]{/Q}
; 
% nodes
\foreach \cc in {n1, o1, o2, q1, q2} 
    \node [circ, color=red] at (\cc) {} ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: output for the MWE]

Comment: I would add a `node[circ]{}` or `to[short,*-]` at every junction (n1, o1, o2, q1 and q2) to distinguish them from mere crossings.

Comment: Many thanks guys, you are awesome. Merry Christmas for you all.

Comment: @JohnKormylo you're definitely right.... I've been too lazy. :-)

Comment: @JohnKormylo done, thanks!

Comment: Also (A5.out -| A4.in 1).  (I missed that one too.)

Comment: @JohnKormylo... yes, I imagine it would be coherent, although I feel it's a bit redundant there. Exercise let for the OP ;-).